# Add input-box when selecting a specific option into select drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, input

I need to add input to a select option when it is selected. Whenever the user selects 'other' an input box is there for the user to enter in data.

HTML:

```
<select>
  <option>Choose Your Name</option>
  <option>Frank</option>
  <option>George</option>
  <option>Other</option>
</select>

<!-- when other is selected add input
<label>Enter your Name
<input></input>
</label> -->
```

My jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rynslmns/CxhGG/1/

Comment: You'll need to use javascript or jQuery - Start here: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use jquery [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) to bind change event of an element.

Try this one:

**HTML**

```
<select>
  <option>Choose Your Name</option>
  <option>Frank</option>
  <option>George</option>
  <option>Other</option>
</select>
<label style="display:none;">Enter your Name
<input></input>
</label>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('select').change(function(){
     if($('select option:selected').text() == "Other"){
        $('label').show();
     }
     else{
        $('label').hide();
     }
 });
```

[Try in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CxhGG/8/)

**Updated:**

You can also add an input-box dynamically -

**HTML**

```
<select>
  <option>Choose Your Name</option>
  <option>Frank</option>
  <option>George</option>
  <option>Other</option>
</select>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('select').change(function(){
   if($('select option:selected').text() == "Other"){
        $('html select').after("<label>Enter your Name<input></input></label>");
   }
   else{
        $('label').remove();
   }
});
```

[Try in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CxhGG/15/)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pure javascript version, no jQuery needed:

```
<script>
// Put this script in header or above select element
    function check(elem) {
        // use one of possible conditions
        // if (elem.value == 'Other')
        if (elem.selectedIndex == 3) {
            document.getElementById("other-div").style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById("other-div").style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>

<select id="mySelect" onChange="check(this);">
        <option>Choose Your Name</option>
        <option>Frank</option>
        <option>George</option>
        <option>Other</option>
</select>
<div id="other-div" style="display:none;">
        <label>Enter your Name
        <input id="other-input"></input>
        </label>
</div>
```

[jsFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/54HCG/)

As stated before, add onChange event, link it to function and there process what should be displayed etc.

Comment: What happens when I need to store the value? 

<input type="text" name="othername" />

Where is name specified for post purposes? It would be ideal to use the same "name" whether the user enters data manually or selects an option.

Comment: You can just use the input field for post, basically ad a name to <input> and inside the check function change it's value to selected option - or set it to empty string if "other" is selected.

Answer (score 2):

[**See it in action here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/MkZW4/)

HTML:

```
<select id="choose">
    <option>Choose Your Name</option>
    <option>Frank</option>
    <option>George</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<label id="otherName">Enter your Name
    <input type="text" name="othername" />
</label>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#choose").on("change", function() {
        if ($(this).val() === "other") {
            $("#otherName").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#otherName").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Note the `value="other"` attribute on the "Other" option. That's how the script determines if the "Other" option is selected.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was going to post a very similar answer. It's on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rynslmns/CxhGG/1/

Comment: you might as well do $("#choose").change(  since its a shortcut for $("#choose").on("change", http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: `.change()` works, yes, but can't be expanded to accommodate event namespaces, if you should choose to implement them. I guess I also just use `.on()` out of habit, hahah.